# Why field isn't set during json deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, postsharp

I have a serialized object which looks like this :

```json
{
  "Var4": "value set in Foo()",
  "var3": "value set in NestedFoo()",
  "<var3>k__OriginalField": "value set in NestedFoo()",
  "<Var4>k__BackingField": "value set in Foo()"
}
```

which comes from this object :

```cs
public class DummyClass 
    {
        [ModificationTrackerAspect]
        public string var3 = "initialValue";
        public string Var4 { get; set; } = "initialValue";
        
    }
```

On var3 there is an attribute which inherits from the Postsharp aspect [LocationInterceptionAspect](https://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception).
This aspect has the side effect of changing the field affected to a property and creating a backing field for this property (the field is `"<var3>k__OriginalField"`.

During serialization everything seems okay, but as I want to deserialize it, I can't get to set the var3 field/property.

The deserialization occures like this :

```cs
instanceTypeName = ... (fetched from a text file);
unknowclassDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, Type.GetType(instanceTypeName));
```

I tried changing the json in the debugger to :

```json
{
  "Var4": "value set in Foo()",
  "var3": "value set in NestedFoo()",
  "<Var4>k__BackingField": "value set in Foo()"
}
```

or

```json
{
  "Var4": "value set in Foo()",
  "Var3": "value set in NestedFoo()",
  "<var3>k__OriginalField": "value set in NestedFoo()",
  "<Var4>k__BackingField": "value set in Foo()"
}
```

and finally :

```json
{
  "Var4": "value set in Foo()",
  "Var3": "value set in NestedFoo()",
  "<Var4>k__BackingField": "value set in Foo()"
}
```

But I always get an object with var4 correctly set and var3 set to it's initial value.
What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: in the postsharp documentation it is said :

> Note that when a LocationInterceptionAspect is added to a field, the field is replaced by a property of the same field and visibility. The field itself is renamed and made private.

Edit 2 : I removed the static variable for clarity and changed the deserialization to reflect my true intentions.

Comment: `var3` isnt a property but a variable, a variable has no backing field. declare it like this `public string var3 { get; set; }`

Comment: @RandRandom I don't want to change var3, this is part of a bigger project where I don't want to change every field into a property. And yes var3 at compile time become a property because of Postsharp see the link about locationInterceptionAspect => https://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception

Comment: Quote from the link : Note that when a LocationInterceptionAspect is added to a field, the field is replaced by a property of the same field and visibility. The field itself is renamed and made private.

Comment: C# is case sensitve your json has `Var3` but your class has it defined as `var3` pick either `V` or `v` in both cases.

Comment: @RandRandom Like I said in my post I tried Both syntax. Look at the 4 JSONs i posted.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/HsdtSs.  `var3` and `Var4  ` are both deserialized successfully.  But you don't include a definition for `ModificationTrackerAspectAttribute` which seems to be your own attribute, so if you can [edit] your question to share a [mcve] then we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You, in my option, have the issue that you have illegal characters in your property names. I would recommend using JsonProperty annotation and a son constructor. Important, loose the static as this memory address would be re-used for each instance of this class making it "singleton" like values, doubt that that is your intention

```
public class DummyClass 
{
    [JsonProperty("Var3")]  
    private string var1 = "initialValue";
    [JsonProperty("Var4")]
    private string Var2 = "initialValue";

    [ModificationTrackerAspect]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Var3 =>var1 ;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Var4 { get=>Var2 ; set=> Var2=value; } 
        
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about "illegal characteres in the property name" as I only use [a-zA-Z] characters. 
And I don't really get what you did with the statics variables but these are real variables and I'm aware of what a static variable implies. For clarity I will remove them as it is not relevant in my question. Also I can't use attributes because I don't know what class I deserialize until runtime. The attribute (ModificationTrackerAspect) is added at compile time with postsharp thanks to a config file.

Comment: I edited my question, I'm sorry for writing it in a way that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Jirochan, "<var3>k__OriginalField" will not map

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute emitted by PostSharp on the property it added.

By default, the default contract resolver ignores all fields/properties with these attributes. You need to override this behavior by setting `SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers` on `DefaultContractResolver`, i.e.:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    before, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings() 
    { 
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() 
        { 
            SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers = true 
        } 
    })
```

If you already have the data serialized, you'll probably need to write your own custom resolver to provide correct mapping.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but at the moment I already modified  the contract resolver and it already serializee everything. It is at deserialization time that it fails. When you say I need to write a custom resolver to provide correct mapping, you mean write a deserializer, or override some properties/methods of JSON.NET ?

Comment: You need to make sure that deserialization too gets JsonProperty representing mapping value from json to `var3` property. Passing the same ContractResolver to `DeserializeObject` should help.